# What's the difference between static and instance members?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to know what the difference between these two functions at this sample class in javascript?

```
class Sample{
  constructor(){}

  sampleOne(){
    console.log('this is test')
  }
  static sampleTwo(){
    console.log('this is test too')
  }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static

Comment: One's called on an instance, one's called on the class. Simple searching would answer this question. (Either one.)

Comment: "*What's the difference between static and instance members?*" and "*When should I use a static member?*" are very different questions.

Comment: p.s.w.g, yes you right I forgot to change the question

Comment: @DaveNewton: "class" and "instance" don't quite apply to Javascript (if you really want to understand what's going on).

Comment: @georg They do if you're pretending JS has classes like ES6 pretends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript doesn't have classes, therefore explanations in terms of "class" and "instance" are inaccurate. In javascript, there are only objects, which have constructors (functions) and prototypes (other objects). The ES6 "class" syntax is just a decorator, which simply translates java-like class declarations into prototypes, namely:

- classes are turned into constructors (functions):

  ```
  class Sample => function Sample()
  ```
- ordinary methods are attached to the `prototype` property of the constructor, and copied to the `object.[[Prototype]]` later on when you do `new Sample()`:

  ```
  sampleOne  => Sample.prototype.sampleOne
  ```
- "static" methods are attached directly to the constructor:

  ```
  sampleTwo  => Sample.sampleTwo
  ```

Illustration:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The first one is an *instance method*. This means, you have to create a new instance of the `Sample` class to call it:

```
let instance = new Sample();
instance.sampleOne();
```

The second one is a *static method*, so you don't have to have an instance of the class to call it:

```
Sample.sampleTwo();
```

Comment: what about `Sample.prototype.sampleOne`? no instance there, but a usable method nonetheless.

Comment: @dandavis Well, it's usable because the body of the method doesn't mention `this`, so you are absolutely right _in regards to the example shown_. However, it is very unlikely to have an instance method which doesn't utilize `this` in reality. If so, what's the point for wrapping it up in a class?

Comment: yopu can call/apply/bind it if it uses _this_. It's the same use as any other method...

Answer (score 0):

`static` is a declaration to say this method `sampleTwo` can be called on the class level and not the instance level. `sampleOne` however, is an instance method and so you would need to instantiate an instance of your sample class.

```
const test = Sample();
test.sampleOne(); //works
test.sampleTwo(); //won't work cause it is defined on class level

Sample.sampleOne(); //won't work cause not static defined
Sample.sampleTwo(); //works because it is static.
```

Comment: My knowledge of js as a prototypical language is unfortunately limited. Hopefully someone comes along who can provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Static methods are not bound to a class instance. But to the class itself. So while convenient you will not have access to `this` as there is no instance to point to.

Comment: what about `Sample.prototype.sampleOne`?

Answer (score -1):

Static methods are called on the class itself.

For example, the following would work perfectly

```
Sample.sampleOne()
// undefined
```

while

```
Sample.sampleTwo()
// this is a test two
```

Comment: @MaheerAli One's not a typo. Although calling `sampleOne()` would throw an error.